# why does my slot get triggered multiple times for only one signal?

Tags: qt, tabs, signals-slots

I want to execute a method for a tab when it gets double clicked. Now what happens, is that my slot gets called as many times as I have tabs (i.e. if I have 3 open tabs and I double click on one, my slot gets invoked three times). Why is this and how do I best troubleshoot and fix this?
My connect call looks like this:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(tabBarDoubleClicked(int)),this, SLOT(editTabLabel(int)));
```

Comment: Are you sure `connect` is not called multiple times? try adding [`Qt::UniqueConnection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum), that way even if it is called multiple times the connection will be setup only once (this is a test only to make sure this is the case).

Comment: @Mike yep, that was it! If you add this as an answer, i'll accept it! Thanks!